# passing value from one page to another using input "type=text" element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

page name 3.html

```
<html>
    <body>
<form action="4.html" onSubmit="cal()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="sen"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="tap me"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    function call(){
        var a = document.getElementById("sen").value;
        localStorage.setItem("a",a);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

page name 4.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
    <tr>
        <td><p id="r"></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>
    var get = localStorage.getItem('sen');
    alert(get);
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML=get;
</script>
</html>
```

i am trying to pass value from 3.html to 4.html but it is passing null value.
why is it passing the null value?
how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an error when calling the function
onSubmit="**cal()**"

The defined function name is **call()**

Apart that you are trying to set the session with key **a** and retrieve it with key **seen**.

Comment: I see i must have forgot to change it after editing the code. Thanks for that. I tried after editing the code but it is not working, giving the same output as before.

Comment: It is working now i just noticed that key part which i am passing it to next page. Thanks for the help.